# An idiom to describe something that takes less effort

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

If I wanted to say that something takes one-tenth of the time, I'd say it is 10 times faster. Is there a similar way to describe something that ***takes one-tenth of the effort***? I'm looking for something better than ***10 times easier***.

I'm trying to come up with a comparative adjective form to indicate that an automated process requires 10 times less effort than a manual process, which typically takes hundreds of hours. Here's an example usage:

> This new product makes security compliance 10 times _______.

All synonyms of *easy* I found seem to suggest *unchallenging*, *effortless*, or *facile*. I was looking for something that was closer to "***gives more leverage***".

Comment: You could say **ten times less strenuous**. But it would help if you gave more context. What do you need it for? _**Man**_, we are quick to downvote!

Comment: @fev I'm trying to write copy for a product that makes something require 10 times less effort. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it possible what that something is?

Comment: @fev sure. The "something" is an information-security compliance. It typically takes hundreds of hours of manual effort. The product makes it 10x less effort.

Comment: Yes, you are new so you might not be aware of the strict rules concerning questions and answers on this site. Have a look at the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a bit more accustomed. Welcome to the ELU!

Comment: Why is “10 times easier” unsuitable?

Comment: @ColleenV it isn't unsuitable as much as it is unusable in this context (because "easy" is overused, and doesn't evoke as clear a picture as, say, "fast"). I felt there should be many synonyms of "easier", and perhaps one of those ought to fit better.

On second thoughts, may be the more succinct way of phrasing this question would have been to ask: synonyms of "easier"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you’re on the right track with *leverage* here:

> **leverage**, *n.*
> **2. b.** *figurative*. Advantage for accomplishing a purpose; increased power of action.
>  <sub>Source: [Oxford English
> Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Leverage multiplies force. The effectiveness of leverage in multiplying force is called *efficiency*:

> **efficiency**, *n.*
> **2. a.** Fitness or power to accomplish, or success in accomplishing, the purpose intended; adequate power, effectiveness, efficacy.
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Your product employs the efficiency of leverage.

So your product makes security compliance **ten times more efficient**.

It offers **ten times the efficiency** of other products.

You can see some [usage examples](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=99835508) from the Corpus of Contemporary American English.

.

<sub>See also: [*Simple Machines, IMA, AMA and Efficiency*](http://bfhsvalle.weebly.com/uploads/8/4/8/0/84808806/ima-ama-_efficiency.pdf) and [*Resource Information for Teaching Simple Machines*](http://www2.phy.ilstu.edu/pte/489.01content/simple_machines/simple_machines.html)</sub>

Comment: Efficient is perfect!